# Selenium - echo Base URL

Tags: selenium, base-url

How can I read the current value of Base URL in Selenium IDE 2.8.0?

Please suggest a working version of following selenese:

```
echo ${BASEURL}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your instance of the IWebDriver and put .Url after it.  This gets the current URL that the driver is associated with.  Then you can use whatever output mechanism you want to use.  So if you go with the echo...

```
    echo ${driver.URL}
```

where `driver` equals your active selenium WebDriver instance.  If you want just the root of the URL then you need to do a regex expression on the returned URL and look for the .com/.net/.org and chop anything after that off.

If you are using php you might want to look here: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/175838-extract-base-url-from-entire-url/

Answer (score 0):

1) Create IWebDriver instance
IwebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();
2) navigate to URL
driver.navigate().to("");
3) Print the URL 
printline("The base URL is " + driver.URL);

(please ignore syntactical and language specific errors)

Comment: I am using Selenium IDE 2.8.0 and not web driver. How can I read the value of Base URL that was typed in the bar?